# bash - Pass variable to a string in a shell file

Tags: python, bash

I'm trying to run a docker command through a bash script but I cannot pass correctly the arguments.

By bash script is:

```
#!/bin/bash

start=$(date -d '13 hours ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H')
end=$(date -d '12 hours ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H')

docker run --rm -v /home/basic/buffer/:/home psycopg2 /bin/sh -c 'python /home/config.py  ${start} ${end} ' > /home/basic/result
```

and my python script is (config.py):

```
import psycopg2
import datetime
import sys

start = "%s" % (sys.argv[1])
end = "%s" % (sys.argv[2])

print("start:",start)
print("end:",end)
```

But it prints empty strings.

Any ideas?

Comment: Change 'python /home/config.py ' "${start}" "${end}" > /home/basic/result to "python /home/config.py '$start' '$end'" > /home/basic/result"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need an additional shell; just quote the parameter expansions so that `docker run` receives the correct arguments; those will be passed directly to Python, without being subject to any further shell processing. in side the container.

```
#!/bin/bash

start=$(date -d '13 hours ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H')
end=$(date -d '12 hours ago' '+%Y-%m-%d %H')

docker run --rm -v /home/basic/buffer/:/home psycopg2 \
  python /home/config.py "${start}" "${end}" > /home/basic/result
```

A quick example:

```
% docker run --rm bash /usr/bin/printf '%s\n' "a b" "c d"
a b
c d
```

`printf` receives three arguments, not five. There is no command like `printf %s\n a b c d` being constructed inside the container.

Comment: I don't get an error with this approach but redirection seems to not work as `/home/basic/result` is an empty file - @chepner